# Not able to connect to MySQL database when reading db parameters from config file

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, configuration

Okay.. I'm having a really strange issue and not able to figure out why it's happening. I have an AWS lambda function (Node.js) which connects to a MySQL database.

1. When DB parameters are hardcoded in Node.js, it works fine.  Please see below.

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : "myapp.something.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user     : "someuser",
    password : "somepassword",
    port     : "3306",
    database : "somedatabse"
});
const query = util.promisify(con.query).bind(con);
```

2. When I try to connect to the DB by reading these parameters from a config file or lambda environment variables, I get this error.

*"ERROR Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)*"

```
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : dbHost,
    user     : dbUser,
    password : dbPassword,
    port     : dbPort,
    database : dbName
});
const query = util.promisify(con.query).bind(con);


// Retrieving DB parameters from my config file like this.  Values are being retrieved successfully.
dbHost = dbConfig.dev_db_host;
dbUser = dbConfig.dev_db_user;
dbPassword = dbConfig.dev_db_password;
dbPort = dbConfig.dev_db_port;
dbName = dbConfig.dev_db_name;

// Able to log all these values correctly.
console.log(dbHost); // myapp.something.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
console.log(dbUser);// someuser
console.log(dbPassword); // somepassword
console.log(dbPort); // 3306
console.log(dbName); // somedatabase
```

Note - I am able to retrieve the values successfully from config file.  I verified by logging the info.  Not sure why the DB connection is failing.
Also, I run into the exact same issue when I read the DB parameters from lambda environment variables.
Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: for the `console.log` can you put some brackets around the output, so we can see if there is unwanted whitespace leading or trailing?

Comment: Hi @SethE.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I've added brackets around the logs but I do not see any unexpected leading or trailing characters.  Please see below.

(myapp.something.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com)
(someuser)
(somepassword)
(3306)
(somedatabase)